# Microsoft Visual C# 2008 Express Edition

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

My 90 day trial period has ended, I tried repair/reinstalling the program but that didn't work.
Is there anyway I can get another trial period?

Answer (score 3):

Visual C# 2008 Express is free, so you can just register your copy with Microsoft to continue using it. You can do the registration from Help -> Register Product.

More info about [Visual Studio Express Registration](http://www.microsoft.com/express/registration/Default.aspx).

Comment: thanks!
I thought I would have to pay to register the software.

Answer (score 2):

Considering your title, you are using Express Editions. Those are free, but require you to register after which you can use it indefinetly. There should be a link to register when you start C# Express Edition.

Answer (score 0):

I think 90 days is long enough to decide whether you want it ;)

As others have said, Express Edition is free anyway :p

Answer (score 0):

It is quite possible that you downloaded the real deal trial of Visual Studio 2008, which does have a limited life span of 90 days.

If you did happen to download the trial version fo visual studio, you don't even need to unintall it. All you need to do is [download](http://www.microsoft.com/express/download/) the correct version of the express version that fits your needs. If you would like to purchase the full version of Visual Studio all you need to do is [search online](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?hl=en&source=hp&q=purchase+visual+studio+2008&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=9908390514598538539&ei=f-QPS6_YMYioMP290DM&sa=X&oi=product_catalog_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CCMQ8wIwAw#ps-sellers) for the edition that you would like to use.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

VS 2010 beta has 365 days trial :), download it